# Why my metallic material seems weird in viewport shading?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders

I change the metallic node to simulate the metal material, but it shows odd in viewport shading.
I have even checked my light is turning on. Please help me to solve this problem. [image]
[image]

Comment: This is a bit of a cheat, but what happens when you up your specularity?

Comment: If you don't have any HDRI image, by default your metallic object will only be able to reflect the background color and the lights, so if you want the same effect as in Material Preview you need an HDRI

Comment: It works when I turn off the scene world lighting and turn on the scene lighting, thanks. However, I get another question. Although I turn off both world and scene lighting, the cube can still reflect the HDRI color and light, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically this is because of different viewport shadings... In picture 1 you are using real time render (red arrow) where your lighting is used without default hdri...
[image]

In 2nd picture you are using viewport shading where there is not shown what render looks like (if you render this, you will get what you see in 1st picture) but you are shown what your object looks like with default hdri that Blender uses like in here:
[image]

Do you see that sphere in red circle? That is what you see in reflections, it is nothing to worry about. If you change it back to realtime render you will see it how it should look like

Comment: It works when I turn on the scene lighting with default hdri. But why the cube can still reflect the HDRI color and light even if I turn off both world and scene lighting(where I select in red arrow)?

Comment: Another question. How can I change back to real-time render to see what it looks like in render mode under the default HDRI setting in blender?